# How to approach dynamically generated Firestore queries depending on nested user created Sub Collections?

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

```
/Countries/Lebanon/Governorates/Mount Lebanon/Districts/Chouf/Cities/Wadi al-Zayneh/Data/Products/Main Categories/Restaurants & Bakeries/Sub Categories/Snack/Sub Categories/Abo Arab Cafe
```

So as you can see, this is a snippet from my current Firestore structure. So many deeply nested collections. The issue is, I want to keep going deeper as long as a collection called 'Sub Categories' is found which in that case I would render them in the UI. And when eventually I reach a level where 'Sub Categories' is not found, I will render a different UI and show the actual products (The last document "Abo Arab Cafe" contains all the products as maps). The pattern of how many Sub Categories there are is unexpectable and can be modified by the end user.
How can I keep checking for Sub Categories? How to manage my queries in a way that they are dynamically generated at each level at the client-side?

I use Flutter. Here is my current queries structure:

```
    import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';

class FirebaseServices {
  final FirebaseFirestore _db = FirebaseFirestore.instance;

  CollectionReference mainCategoryCollectionReference() {
    CollectionReference mainCategoryCollectionReference = _db.collection(
        '/Countries/Lebanon/Governorates/Mount Lebanon/Districts/Chouf/Cities/Wadi al-Zayneh/Data/Products/Main Categories');

    return mainCategoryCollectionReference;
  }

  CollectionReference subCategoryCollectionReference(
      String parentSelectedCategory) {
    CollectionReference mainCategoryCollectionReference = _db.collection(
        '/Countries/Lebanon/Governorates/Mount Lebanon/Districts/Chouf/Cities/Wadi al-Zayneh/Data/Products/Main Categories/$parentSelectedCategory/Sub Categories');

    return mainCategoryCollectionReference;
  }

  bool checkIfSubCategoriesExist(CollectionReference collectionReference) {
    bool subCategoriesExist;

    collectionReference.get().then((value) => {
          subCategoriesExist = value.docs.isNotEmpty,
          print('SubCategoriesExist: $subCategoriesExist')
        });
    return subCategoriesExist;
  }
}
```

This works only if I know for certain how many levels of deepness there are, but since this can be modified by the user, it won't work.
Sorry for the very long question I had no idea how to explain it properly and clearly. 
Thank you in advance!

Comment: what is the purpose of this application?

Comment: @PeterHaddad it is an ecommerce platform. Will contain 4 applications(Admin, Stores, Delivery, and Customer). 

The store app will let the store owners post the products and manage their details, categories (can add and remove sub categories and organize products accordingly).

Customers will then view the products and be able to order them.

Delivery will show the current customer orders to be delivered.

Admin will be supervising over all of the activities with special privileges on the database for a particular area.

Answer (score 2):

The structure is all wrong, there is no point in the structure being this deeply nested. The structure of the database needs to match what has to appear in the UI.

Assuming this is a worldwide application since you are using `countries` then you have to do the following:

| Collection | Document | Fields |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Countries | Random ID | countryName - arrayOfDistrict- arrayOfGovernorates |

3 Fields under each document id, containing information about the country.

Then regarding Resturants:

| Collection | Document | Fields | SubCollection | subCollectionId | Fields |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Resturant | Random ID | resturant_name- resturant_location - info_about_resturant | Menu | randomId | dish_name - price -... |

The problem with your db structure is that it is very nested instead of making a flat structure and that right now you are harcoding the whole path.

Using the above structure, you can create a dropdown with list of countries if the user chooses Lebanon, then you get the districts and the governorates. Then you can do a call to get the resturants that are inside each district, since in the documents inside `Resturant` collection you can get location of each resturant and name.

After that on click of each resturant, you will get the data inside the subcollection that will contain the full menu.

Comment: Thank you so much Peter! This seems and feels more reasonable than my current structure. I am new to NoSequel DBs and still getting my head around it. However, the app will include almost all types of stores and shops, including food places like restaurants and bakeries/supermarkets ...etc. Is it feasible if I contacted you on slack for more details please? or do you prefer another place? I live in Lebanon too btw!

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the solution with the help of a friend!

Since the checkIfSubCategoriesExist function is always checking on the very last reached level(using the collectionReference argument) whether Sub Categories exists or not, he suggested that in case it does exist, I can append to its argument collectionReference the new "Sub Categories" String to the path as a variable! This way I can query on it and voila!